Populate OneDrive folder from local backup without affecting remote files
I have quite a few gigabytes of files stored on OneDrive, but I also keep a local backup copy everything. Recently, I had to reformat my laptop's hard drive. Currently, I have re-installed Windows 10 and I have it set up with OneDrive logged in, but files are available "On-Demand", meaning they are online-only until I try to open them.
Here's my question: since I have a full backup of my OneDrive files (and since I use mobile data for internet), can I save data by repopulating the local OneDrive folder from my backup, perhaps by overwriting all the placeholder files and folders in OneDrive, but without affecting remote files on the OneDrive server? Can I be certain that it will not then try to re-upload and overwrite all my files, or create duplicate copies of them all?
NOTE: I realize that my question is similar to this post from over 10 years ago, but my use case is a little different in that the files are already live on the server, and OneDrive's "On-Demand" feature has been introduced since then.
